# Can you help, is there something wrong in my code

Tags: java, list, class, arraylist

I have a main class and then when I divide each element (id, name, surname, ...) then I should to save it in the list in another class called Student, and there class students. There are errors such as "method Collection.add(String[]) is not applicable". So what is the problem?

```
public class ProjectWork{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
        int i;
        String str,name="",surname="",id="";
        String [] midterms = new String[3];
        while(fin.hasNextLine()){
            str = fin.nextLine();
            StringTokenizer toks = new StringTokenizer(str,"|");
            while(toks.hasMoreTokens()){
                id = toks.nextToken();
                name = toks.nextToken();
                surname = toks.nextToken();
                for(i=0;i<3;i++){
                    midterms[i] = toks.nextToken();
                }
            }
            Student(id,name,surname,midterms);
        }
    }

    public static void Student(String id, String name, String surname, String[] midterms) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException{
         private List<String[]> students = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        students.add(id);
        students.add(name);
        students.add(surname);
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean, A) your code doesn't resemble what you say you're supposed to do, and B) It's telling you exactly what the problem is; you're trying to add a `String` to a `List<String[]>`

Comment: It's not clear what Student is here. Is it supposed to be an inner class of ProjectWork? Or is declared elsewhere and imported? Either way, the line public static void Student(...) doesn't make sense. Nor does your use of the private on the students variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, see this line:

```
private List<String[]> students = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

It accepts Array of string, where as you are adding only String like this:

```
students.add(id);
```

So you are getting that error. Either declare `students` like this:

```
private List<String> students = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Or add "String" array using `add` method.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared that you collection, `students` should take `String` arrays...

```
List<String[]> students = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

But you are trying adding `String` elements to it, which are not the same thing.

Either change it so it does add `String[]` arrays...

```
List<String[]> students = new ArrayList<String[]>();
students.add(new String[]{id,name, surname});
```

or redecalre it to take `String`

```
List<String> students = new ArrayList<String>();
students.add(id);
students.add(name);
students.add(surname);
```

Based on what I understand your code is trying to do, I think you want the first one.

(ps- Local variables cannot be declared with access modifiers (ie `private`), you'll want to get rid of that)

Overall, you code doesn't make a lot of sense.  You're calling a `static` method `Student`, which creates a `List`, adds some elements to it and the discards all that work when it exist.  Is `Student` suppose to be a class?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add String objects to a List, change this because you are not adding three arrays of type String:

```
private List<String> students = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the students type as Array of String. So you should add an array to the collection.

To add id, name, surname, You can declare the collection type as String.
ie  List<String> students = new ArrayList<String>();

The method should be like this:

public static void Student(String id, String name, String surname, String[] midterms) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException { 
        //List<String[]> students = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        List<String> students = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        students.add(id);
        students.add(name);
        students.add(surname); 
    }